# Alternatives for SharePoint date field calender

Tags: sharepoint-designer, datetimecontrol

Our users complaints that the date calendar control on SharePoint forms are not user friendly. And you can navigate only month by month as shown in below image.

[image]

I found this article to replace the calendar with jquery:
[How to replace the SharePoint date calendar control with more user friendly jQuery calendar control](https://ybbest.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-replace-the-sharepoint-date-calendar-control-with-more-user-friendly-jquery-calendar-control/)

Is there any other alternatives available for calendar on datetime control using Out of box or by customization?

Comment: http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI DatePicker Control](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to have a responsive nice looking calender control.

Usage:

**1**. Include the jQuery UI JS script in your forms or add them globally.

**2**. Replace **Name** with the internal name of the DateTime column and put the above code in your global JS or using a Script Editor web part on the List forms.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[title='*Name']").datepicker();
});
```

**3**. You can use various options provided by the framework to customize the behavior of this control

Another alternative is to use [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) DatePicker control built over Bootstrap 3 which is also a nice responsive control with loads of options to customize.